# Consul and HA Proxy for Service Discovery - Which should I use?

Tags: haproxy, consul

I know that Consul is a tool for Service Discovery in the era of micro-services. But before Consul, HA Proxy was invented. So why do we need Consul for service discovery, or Consul is more powerful than HA Proxy? Is there any comparisons between Consul and HA Proxy? Please give me some advice, which should I use or can I use both of them.

Answer (score 5):

HA Proxy is basically a high performance TCP/HTTP laod balancer and Consul provides both a DNS and HTTP interface for doing service discovery(Consul also provides other features as Key/Value store etc.)

Here is an article as to how you can use both HA proxy and consul [together](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html):

Another article [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/autoscaled-load-balancing-using-haproxy-and-consul-on-compute-engine) refers to dynamic load balancing using both these tools.

If you are using docker, you might want to look at this basic setup [article](http://sirile.github.io/2015/05/18/using-haproxy-and-consul-for-dynamic-service-discovery-on-docker.html).

PS : I haven't tried using Consul together with HA Proxy though I am working on two separate POC to use them in separate situations. I hope these articles will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Consul to find out that on which IPs and ports your service is running and then based on this info generate HAProxy config. Clients communication to backends would go via the HAProxy load balancer and they don't need to know about internal ips, ports or even Consul. Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073576/consul-sd-architecture-what-is-the-right-way-to-access-microservices-from-a-fr) question regarding service discovery.